# Adding any of "age of empires" tags to favorites, adds extra tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, watched-tags

When i edit my "Favorite Tags" and add `age-of-empires-2`, it gets normally added but in addition to the tag i added, i get 2 extra tags: `of` and `age`.

[image]

Same problem seems to occur with other `age of empire` tags.

Is this a bug or intended?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue is happening because you typed out "age of" and then clicked "age-of-empires-2" from the suggestion drop down that shows up. When you do that it adds "age-of-empires-2", but it doesn't remove the "age of" tags that you included. I'm assuming this is expected behaviour, since it lets you add multiple tags at once.  In order to avoid this issue, just don't include spaces between words in the tags.

Answer (score 5):

The tags aren't "age of empires" but "age-of-empires". Spaces aren't allowed in tag names (they separate different tags)